# Allow to translate http to https migration revision text

Tags: feature-request, community-user, localization, ssl

Is it possible to make string like [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3193/revisions) one in revision list:

> replaced http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ with https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

translatable via standard SE translation mechanism?

I suppose that some strings may already been hardcoded into the QA database, but I know that at least one, in particular [[Edit removed during grace period]](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/458) is available to translate even for an old revisions, as you can see in related question on ruSO meta: [Отсутствует перевод описания ревизии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3193/176217)

Comment: Not sure if it's possible. I guess the difference is that the edits for HTTPS migration were input "manually" by a script, while the "edit removed during grace period" is a system text.